# Worst case runtime of a for loop with a method inside the for loop thats runtime is Big O(log n)

Tags: time-complexity, runtime

Say that I have a block of code like

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    randomFuntion(); // runtimes function is O(log n)
}
```

Would this have an overall worst-case runtime of O(n) or would it just be O(n log n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n logn for sure. Because the O(logn) bound function is always executed n times.